# Vue.js weird behavior of router after refreshing page

Tags: vue.js

I have a problem with dynamic routes in my vue.js application. When i enter page from a routerLink click everything works as it should. But when i refresh that page or i enter there from normal href the page acts weird. It looks then like it's not loading static assets like styles which were reset in public/style.css. Also component lifecycle methods are not firing up (created(), mounted() etc.).

Reproduction here: 
1. Enter https://blooming-dusk-66903.herokuapp.com/profiles
2. Enter on one of profiles
3. Refresh when on https://blooming-dusk-66903.herokuapp.com/profiles/*******

here is my router file

```
Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/landing",
      name: "Landing",
      component: Landing
    },
    {
      path: "/register",
      name: "RegisterForm",
      component: RegisterForm
    },
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "Dashboard",
      component: Dashboard
    },
    {
      path: "/profile",
      name: "UserProfile",
      component: UserProfile
    },
    {
      path: "/profile/:id",
      name: "Profile",
      component: Profile
    },
    {
      path: "/edit-profile",
      name: "EditProfile",
      component: EditProfile
    },
    {
      path: "/friends",
      name: "Friends",
      component: Friends
    },
    {
      path: "/profiles",
      name: "Profiles",
      component: Profiles
    },
    {
      path: "/friend-requests",
      name: "FriendRequests",
      component: FriendRequests
    },
    {
      path: "/post/:id",
      name: "Post",
      component: Post
    },
    {
      path: "/chat/:handle",
      name: "ChatWith",
      component: ChatWith
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Looks like you just need to add `/` before `style.css`

Comment: omg that's it. thanks.